# Why does pip freeze report some packages in a fresh virtualenv created with --no-site-packages?

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv, pip

When I create a fresh virtualenv, `pip freeze` shows that I have a couple of packages installed even though I've not installed anything into the environment. I was expecting `pip freeze` to return empty output until after my first `pip install` into the environment. [wsgiref is part of the standard library](http://docs.python.org/library/wsgiref.html) isn't it, so why does it show up at all?

```
day@garage:~$ mkdir testing
day@garage:~$ cd testing
day@garage:~/testing$ virtualenv --no-site-packages .
New python executable in ./bin/python
Installing distribute..........................................................
...............................................................................
.........................................done.
day@garage:~/testing$ . bin/activate
(testing)day@garage:~/testing$ pip freeze
distribute==0.6.10
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Some extra info:

```
(testing)day@garage:~/testing$ pip --version
pip 0.7.2 from /home/day/testing/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-0.7.2-py2.7.eg
g (python 2.7)
(testing)day@garage:~/testing$ deactivate
day@garage:~/testing$ virtualenv --version
1.4.9
day@garage:~/testing$ which virtualenv
/usr/bin/virtualenv
day@garage:~/testing$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/virtualenv
python-virtualenv: /usr/bin/virtualenv
day@garage:~/testing$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=11.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=natty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 11.04"
```

Comment: distribute is what provides pip itself, so if you want to be able to use pip to install things in your virtualenv you need to start out with pip. pip depends on wsgiref.

Comment: pip does not depend on wsgiref

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Everytime you create a virtualenv with --no-site-packages it installs `setuptools` or `distribute`. And the reason `wsgiref` appears is because python 2.5+ standard library provides egg info to `wsgiref` lib (and `pip` does not know if it stdlib or 3rd party package).

It seems to be solved on Python3.3+: http://bugs.python.org/issue12218

Comment: So is it safe to remove wsgiref? Thanks for the info!

Comment: No, it is not safe to remove it, since `wsgiref` is part of the python standard library: http://docs.python.org/library/wsgiref.html

Comment: Yes, you should not remove `wsgiref` itself. But it is safe to remove the `wsgiref` line from your [requirements.txt](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html) if you have generated that from the output of `pip freeze`.

Comment: This is really strange. I created a fresh virtualenv and installed a few packages. When I did a `pip freeze` only the installed packages showed up. Two days later I installed some more packages and all of sudden `pip freeze` showed `distribute` and `wsgiref`. Why was it even clean in the first place?!?

Answer (score 30):

To answer a slightly different question: you can exclude `wsgiref` (and any other similarly-problematic `.egg` files if you are unfortunate enough to have any for some reason) by doing `pip freeze -l` instead of `pip freeze`.

`pip help freeze` describes this option:

> -l, --local           If in a virtualenv, do not report globally-installed packages

Comment: Took me too long to find this answer. I needed the `-l`