# Why is pip adding extra dependencies to my djangoapp when i run virtualenv?

Tags: python, django, heroku, virtualenv, pip

I'm following [herokus getting-started guide for Django](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django).

I've set-uped and sourced an virtual env:

```
virtualenv venv --distribute

source venv/bin/activate
```

after this I try to install a few things:

```
pip install Django psycopg2 dj-database-url
```

I create a project and pip freeze the requirements. At this point I get two extra requirements:

```
Django==1.4.1
distribute==0.6.28
dj-database-url==0.2.1
psycopg2==2.4.5
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

Where did they come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You requested to install distribute instead of setuptools by including `--distribute` flag while creating virtualenv. And wsgiref is installed also at start, please see [Why does pip freeze report some packages in a fresh virtualenv created with --no-site-packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627035/why-does-pip-freeze-report-some-packages-in-a-fresh-virtualenv-created-with-no)