# After installing Flask + gunicorn pip has unexpected dependencies

Tags: python, flask, pip

After creating a fresh folder and creating a virtual environment

```
$ virtualenv venv --distribute
```

And installing two packages

```
$ pip install Flask gunicorn
```

Then writing all of the current pip installed packages to a file

```
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
$ cat requirements.txt
Flask==0.10.1
Jinja2==2.7
MarkupSafe==0.18
Werkzeug==0.9.1
distribute==0.6.34
gunicorn==17.5
itsdangerous==0.22
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

I get this longer than expected list of packages, who is responsible for them being installed and what are they used for? The package list in question:

```
wsgiref==0.1.2
itsdangerous==0.22
distribute==0.6.34
MarkupSafe==0.18
```

I've used pip mostly on my Ubuntu box, and didn't have these packages installed after identical commands, I've noticed this behaviour only on my mac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`wsgiref` and `distribute` are always present in the virtualenv, even an "empty" one where you have not yet `pip install`'ed anything. See the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6631635/445073) to my question [Why does pip freeze report some packages in a fresh virtualenv created with --no-site-packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6627035/445073) for an explanation. Note this is [a bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue12218) fixed in Python 3.3.

`itsdangerous` and `MarkupSafe` are relatively recent, new dependencies pulled in by newer `Flask` releases.

- `itsdangerous` ([docs](http://pythonhosted.org/itsdangerous/)) is required by `Flask` directly. Since version 0.10 - see the [github commit](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/commit/3f82d1b68ea6f5bf2970c2df8ff5cf991439a9bf#L1R95) which added this dependency.
- `MarkupSafe` ([docs](http://www.pocoo.org/projects/markupsafe/)) is required by `Jinja2` which is required by `Flask`. `Jinja2` added this dependency in its version 2.7 - see the [github commit](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/jinja2/commit/294f2ebff9c312b041d22d4e9d92e5b0c9e7dd86#L6R83).

You say that these are not installed on your Ubuntu box after running identical commands. But what version of `Flask` and `Jinja2` do you have there? If they are older than the versions on your Mac, that might explain why they didn't pull in these new dependencies.

Comment: You're absolutely right, my experience with Ubuntu Flask is not as recent, so both dependencies seem to have been added sometime after that. Brilliant answer!

Answer (score 1):

it looks like those are `Flask` [dependencies](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/installation/), (or dependencies of the flask dependencies)

`pip install --no-install --verbose Flask`

I was hoping [pypi had a list of dependencie](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask)s for each project, but I didn't see them...

Comment: Indeed, thanks! Though there are two dependencies still left unexplained `wsgiref` and  `distribute`

Comment: @MorganWilde Indeed. That's a bug. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17665936/445073)

Answer (score 1):

Your virtualenv uses the packages installed system wide, so pip sees them along your newly installed ones.

Try adding the `--no-site-packages` option when creating your environment.

Or, try to explicitly run the pip instance installed in your environment
(`path/to/your/env/bin/pip opts...`), maybe this will tell pip to ignore system's packages (not sure about that one at all).

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on your point "venv uses packages installed system wide"? I personally don't remember installing any packages system wide, unless by accident... Is there a way to check what's installed system wide @astrognocci?

Comment: @Morgan Wilde: to check whats installed system wide, just do pip freeze while not in a virtualenv (pip needs to be installed on the system too. apt-get install python-pip on a debian like machine).  I had some issues with this a while ago, I was trying to install nosetests inside a venv and pip, detecting the system's one, just aborted instead of getting a new instance of it.  I think dm03514 got the right answer, tho.

Comment: Thanks for indulging me, one more observation - after checking my system wide pip's, I did see far more of them than made the list in my question. How would you explain that if your original premise is - pip sees all of them along newly installed ones? @astrognocci

Comment: I'll admit i'm still confused about this, and my answer is probably wrong. I just ran a global pip freeze from within a virtual env, and while it certainly doesn't list ALL global packages, it does list django or request, which i have NOT installed in this env. The trouble with installing nosetests led me to believe it would list them all, but there's apparently more to it.

Comment: It seems so, oh well, it still was stimulating, your answer. Good luck in your efforts!